# Your app called glInvalidateFramebuffer before presenting renderbuffer

Tags: opengl-es, ios10, glkit

*"Your app called `glInvalidateFramebuffer` before presenting renderbuffer"* is an error message I get in the line:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"myAppDelegate");
```

of my main.m file.

There is not a single call to the `glInvalidateFramebuffer` method in my project. What is more, the project uses OpenGL ES 2.0 (running with a `GLKView`) and the problematic method is part of OpenGL ES 3.0.

I use a number of offscreen frame buffers to draw procedural textures. This error was not notified before iOS 10. Also, it does not prevent rendering, does not show any visible issues and it is impossible to indicate its exact place in code (other than `main.m`) using Capture Frame.

Comment: You normally *want* to invalidate before present (e.g. depth and stencil are normally transient so you don't want to keep them or even write them out to memory, especially on a tile-based renderer). This just looks like a bad error message to me.

Comment: On iOS you can capture a frame which will then show you all the calls that have been made on the openGL API. It might help you get a bit more information on what is going on. But in general avoid the GLK at all cost, I know it helps when starting an application but over time it just restricts your control over the application pipeline so you can easily end up with errors like this one.

Comment: Just for Reference. When I doing Multisampling Anti-Alias, I get the same message with Instruments 8, but switch to Instruments 7 the message is gone. I'm not running with GLKView, CAEAGLLayer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly a false alarm by XCode's GPU Report.

When presenting, both the multi sample buffer and the depth buffer are no longer required.
The multi sample buffer has already been resolved, and to present the pixels, the depth values are no longer necessary.

This means that GLKView does the correct thing: invalidate them before presenting.

Note: the false warning goes away with GLKViewDrawableMultisampleNone instead of 4x.

So in GLK's case, it is triggered by the invalidation of the multi sample buffer after resolving.

Answer (score 0):

Just for Reference. When I doing Multisampling Anti-Alias, I get the same message with Instruments 8, but switch to Instruments 7 the message is gone. I'm not running with GLKView, CAEAGLLayer instead.